# Why does my background flash white when I change the css background property with a transition set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have the following code for my background:

```
.contact {
    @include background(linear-gradient(#3e72ab, #39699d));
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
    height: 500px;

    transition: background 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: background 1s linear; /* FF 4 */
    -webkit-transition: background 1s linear; /* Safari & Chrome */
    -o-transition: background 1s linear; /* Opera */
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

And the following JavaScript to change the background when a submit button is clicked:

```
    $(".contact input[type='submit']").click(function() {
        $(".contact").css({"background":"#2ea930"});
    });
```

But when I click the submit button there's a white flash. Why is this caused? It flashes white then to green as intended. How do I stop this?

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle so we can see it in action?

Comment: background gradients transitions aren't well supported, may be you should look for an alternate method

Comment: I don't think you should try transitioning between a background-image and a background-color. Turn both the old background and the new background into the same type (i.e. both background-images, and use gradients for both).

Comment: **Gradients can't be transitioned** to a color, image or a different gradient.

Answer (score 1):

The flash to white happens when the CSS changes and is reloaded. The white flash you see is the transition during the microseconds it takes to rewrite the CSS.

I recommend to layer your transition on top of another background. The "white flash" is really .contact element being fully transparent for a split second.

Pseudo code:

```
.baseBackground {
     background: linear-gradient(#3e72ab, #39699d);
}

.contact {
    background: linear-gradient(#3e72ab, #39699d);
}

/* On change for .contact  */
.contact {
background-color: #2ea930;
}

<div class="baseBackground">
    <div class="contact"> This div changes </div>
</div>
```